# Opening a saved rchart html file

Tags: html, r, highcharts, rstudio

I created some charts using highcharts and it worked fine in RStudio. I saved it with this command:

```
d3chart$save('d3chart.html', cdn=TRUE)
```

It is saved under my working directory. However, when I clicked the file, the browser opens blank and does not display the charts. I would like to know how to go about displaying the highcharts via clicking the html file in my wd. Thanks.

Comment: Is it d3 chart or highchart?

Comment: @SebastianBochan hi its highcharts. The command can be taken as:

Highcharts$save('filename.html', cdn = TRUE)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as you. I fixed it using this command:

```
 d3chart$save('d3chart.html', standalone=TRUE)
```

I expect that this will help you.

Cheers!!